# What is the most effective use of body slams?

Tags: burrito-bison-launcha

I tend to just use body slams as I get them, but is there any strategy to how I should be using them for maximum effect?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From my experience the best time to use slams is in one of three situations.

- When you are about to land on the ground and not bounce off a gummy bear. Slamming in this situations keeps your speed and altitude up so you don't lose as much speed and height which can be a pain to get back.
- The second is when you see a large group of gummies on the ground. By slamming into a group you can get more money due to the slam destroying more gummies than just one like a normal bounce would.
- The third situation is when you see a special gummy you can use to either speed or get more altitude. If you happen to notice a special gummy and you are above it you can use the slam to hit the special gummy and boost yourself further.